# How can i link to my bootstrap.min.css in a JSP file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, netbeans

I am unable to set the correct path in the JSP file and in the Dispatcher Servlet.

The following image is the `index.jsp` to which I want to apply the css and it also presents the path to the `bootstrap.min.css`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are trying to access the file is wrong.

you are using . operator to access which is not possible.

Try with bootstrap cdn like below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked. Now, If I have a requirement of adding a same style sheet across the multiple JSP files, do I then have to mention the above link tag in all those pages or is there a way around. Also, do I have to make any entries in the Dispatcher Servlet file about the bootstrap so that it works @Alien

Comment: have a look at https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tagreference.html jsp tiles so you need to call only once that can be you header.jsp page